# Number of possible ways the games could have happened

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> 3 players A,B,C are playing a game in the following way:
> One player stays out and the other two play,The loser goes out and the the winner plays with the other player.
> At the end player A has played 15 times,B 14 and C 9.
> What is the number of ways that the games could have happened?

This can be solved by finding the number of (A,B),(A,C),(B,C) games  that are 10,5,4 respectively and a permutation $ \frac{9!}{4! \cdot 5!}=126 $
I was wondering how could one solve it if the word “played” was replaced by “won”. I tried finding a similar way but it did not seem to work.

Comment: The question is how to determine how many games that $A$ won.  I think that you can come close, but not give an exact answer, for two reasons: [1] you dont' know if A played in the first game.  [2] if A played in the last game, you can't tell if he won or lost.  Besides those considerations, you can **guestimate** that $A$ lost **about**  $4$ games, because he played in all but $4$ of the games played.